# NodeMCU SMTP Email

Tags: email, lua, smtp, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm working with NodeMCU (docs here http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/) trying to send an email through SMTP.  I got this script off the net and everything seems to be working okay as there are no errors but I don't see any emails in my box, so something must be going wrong. Using the display function as the send callback prints nil unfortunately.

I was able to send smtp email through simple curl so I know that google will accept smtp requests through command line and these settings are correct.  Also according to this thread it is possible, they are doing the same thing sending raw strings to gmail's smtp service (http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=1231&start=8).

```
-- The email and password from the account you want to send emails from
MY_EMAIL = "REDACTED"
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "REDACTED"

-- The SMTP server and port of your email provider.
-- If you don't know it google [my email provider] SMTP settings
SMTP_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT = "465"

-- The account you want to send email to
mail_to = "REDACTED"

-- Your access point's SSID and password
SSID = "REDACTED"
SSID_PASSWORD = "REDACTED"

-- configure ESP as a station
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(SSID,SSID_PASSWORD)
wifi.sta.autoconnect(1)

email_subject = ""
email_body = ""
count = 0


local smtp_socket = nil -- will be used as socket to email server

-- The display() function will be used to print the SMTP server's response
function display(sck,response)
     print(response)
end

-- The do_next() function is used to send the SMTP commands to the SMTP server in the required sequence.
-- I was going to use socket callbacks but the code would not run callbacks after the first 3.
function do_next()
            if(count == 0)then
                count = count+1
                IP_ADDRESS = wifi.sta.getip()
                smtp_socket:send("HELO "..IP_ADDRESS.."\r\n")
            elseif(count==1) then
                count = count+1
                smtp_socket:send("AUTH LOGIN\r\n")
            elseif(count == 2) then
                count = count + 1
                smtp_socket:send("REDACTED".."\r\n")
            elseif(count == 3) then
                count = count + 1
                smtp_socket:send("REDACTED".."\r\n")
            elseif(count==4) then
                count = count+1
               smtp_socket:send("MAIL FROM:<" .. MY_EMAIL .. ">\r\n")
            elseif(count==5) then
                count = count+1
               smtp_socket:send("RCPT TO:<" .. mail_to ..">\r\n")
            elseif(count==6) then
                count = count+1
               smtp_socket:send("DATA\r\n")
            elseif(count==7) then
                count = count+1
                local message = string.gsub(
                "From: \"".. MY_EMAIL .."\"<"..MY_EMAIL..">\r\n" ..
                "To: \"".. mail_to .. "\"<".. mail_to..">\r\n"..
                "Subject: ".. email_subject .. "\r\n\r\n"  ..
                email_body,"\r\n.\r\n","")

                smtp_socket:send(message.."\r\n.\r\n")
            elseif(count==8) then
               count = count+1
                 tmr.stop(0)
                 smtp_socket:send("QUIT\r\n")
                 print("msg sent")
            else
               smtp_socket:close()
            end
            print(count)
end

-- The connectted() function is executed when the SMTP socket is connected to the SMTP server.
-- This function will create a timer to call the do_next function which will send the SMTP commands
-- in sequence, one by one, every 5000 seconds. 
-- You can change the time to be smaller if that works for you, I used 5000ms just because.
function connected(sck)
    tmr.alarm(0,5000,1,do_next)
end

-- @name send_email
-- @description Will initiated a socket connection to the SMTP server and trigger the connected() function
-- @param subject The email's subject
-- @param body The email's body
function send_email(subject,body)

     count = 0
     email_subject = subject
     email_body = body
     smtp_socket = net.createConnection(net.TCP,0)
     smtp_socket:on("connection",connected)
     smtp_socket:on("receive",display)
    smtp_socket:connect(SMTP_PORT, SMTP_SERVER)     
end
-- Send an email
send_email("ESP8266", "[[Hi, How are your IoT projects coming along? Best Wishes,ESP8266]]")
```

I am available to answer questions regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- The old example from esp8266.com you mentioned uses consecutive `socket:send` calls which doesn't work anymore in recent firmwares, see http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend. It was a "bug" in the SDK this ever worked.
- SMTP port 465 usually implies SSL/TLS connections. You need a firmware that supports that. Otherwise use port 25.
- There's an example right in the NodeMCU repo at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/lua_examples/email/send_email_smtp.lua
- I assume you *did* replace the placeholder at `do_next` count 2/3 with the base64 encoded username and password? Contrary to the example script which requires a Lua encoder module you may want to use the corresponding NodeMCU module, see http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/encoder/#encodertobase64.

I took your script, a recent NodeMCU firmware, changed port to 25, added base64 encode user/pw and was able to successfully deliver an email to myself.

**Update 2016-07-05**

Full script including WiFi init.

```
MY_EMAIL = "myself@my-TLD.com"
MY_EMAIL_B64 = "base64-encoded-email"
EMAIL_PASSWORD_B64 = "base64-encoded-password"

SMTP_SERVER = "my-ISPs-server"
SMTP_PORT = 25

mail_to = "myself@my-TLD.com"

email_subject = ""
email_body = ""
count = 0

smtp_socket = nil

function display(sck,response)
  print(response)
end

function do_next()
  if(count == 0)then
    count = count+1
    local IP_ADDRESS = wifi.sta.getip()
    smtp_socket:send("HELO "..IP_ADDRESS.."\r\n")
  elseif(count==1) then
    count = count+1
    smtp_socket:send("AUTH LOGIN\r\n")
  elseif(count == 2) then
    count = count + 1
    smtp_socket:send(MY_EMAIL_B64.."\r\n")
  elseif(count == 3) then
    count = count + 1
    smtp_socket:send(EMAIL_PASSWORD_B64.."\r\n")
  elseif(count==4) then
    count = count+1
    smtp_socket:send("MAIL FROM:<" .. MY_EMAIL .. ">\r\n")
  elseif(count==5) then
    count = count+1
    smtp_socket:send("RCPT TO:<" .. mail_to ..">\r\n")
  elseif(count==6) then
    count = count+1
    smtp_socket:send("DATA\r\n")
  elseif(count==7) then
    count = count+1
    local message = string.gsub(
      "From: \"".. MY_EMAIL .."\"<"..MY_EMAIL..">\r\n" ..
              "To: \"".. mail_to .. "\"<".. mail_to..">\r\n"..
              "Subject: ".. email_subject .. "\r\n\r\n"  ..
              email_body,"\r\n.\r\n","")

    smtp_socket:send(message.."\r\n.\r\n")
  elseif(count==8) then
    count = count+1
    tmr.stop(0)
    smtp_socket:send("QUIT\r\n")
  else
    smtp_socket:close()
  end
end

function connected(sck)
  tmr.alarm(0,3000,1,do_next)
end

function send_email(subject,body)
  count = 0
  email_subject = subject
  email_body = body
  smtp_socket = net.createConnection(net.TCP,0)
  smtp_socket:on("connection",connected)
  smtp_socket:on("receive",display)
  smtp_socket:connect(SMTP_PORT,SMTP_SERVER)
end

SSID = "my-SSID"
SSID_PASSWORD = "my-WiFi-password"
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(SSID,SSID_PASSWORD)

tmr.alarm(1, 1000, 1, function()
  if wifi.sta.getip()== nil then
    print("IP unavaiable, Waiting...")
  else
    tmr.stop(1)
    print("Config done, IP is "..wifi.sta.getip())
    send_email(
      "ESP8266",
      [[Hi,
      How are your IoT projects coming along?
      Best Wishes,
      ESP8266]])
  end
end)
```

Comment: It still does not work.  I changed the port to 25 and made sure to follow the other instructions and it tells me that I need to issue a starttls command.  If I do that it still refuses to work.  Did you do anything else to change the script to make it work?  Did you change the consecutive send calls to be callbacks like you showed in the net:send docs?

Comment: It's been a while and I dumped my test script in the meantime but I quickly re-assembled it. I doubt Gmail will accept StartTLS on port 25...In fact, I have no idea whether Google accepts unencrypted connections at all. So, you really might have to build a firmware with SSL enabled. There are no consecutive `send` calls in this script (i.e. a NodeMCU example script), due to the timer they're a few seconds apart.

Comment: Sorry I'm just kind of confused.  You said that it worked for you by using port 25 but you're not sure if gmail will accept unencrypted connections?  If you got it working on port 25 isn't that gmail accepting the unsecured connection?

Comment: I now realize what the source of the confusion is, sorry. I use `SMTP_SERVER = "my-ISPs-server"` which indicates I'm _not_ using the Gmail infrastructure - I don't have a Google mail account. I may be able to "borrow" a colleague's account to verify, though.

Comment: I see, thank you.  I will be trying this tomorrow with my email @gmx.com which uses smtp port 25 so hopefully it will work.

Comment: I managed to get it working using my email @gmx.com.  Had to switch to EHLO rather than HELO for some reason that I can't really explain, but I did manage to recieve an email from my gmx account.  Thank you for your help and also thanks for your firmware build service, quite helpful.

Comment: Great, glad you got it fixed. Odd that `HELO` wouldn't work as its support is mandatory. [EHLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP) is for extended SMTP. "EHLO indicates that the client supports at least one of several possible extensions that are not part of the basic SMTP specification. HELO indicates that it does not, and that only the minimum SMTP set will be used when talking to this server."

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I had another roadblock where the code is acting quite funny, and decided to make a fresh question rather than having an extended discussion in the comments.  If you feel like touching on this one the url is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232100/nodemcu-timeout-when-using-while-loop